# EDB jdbc argument for applicationName property

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc

On my local postgres database I can connect with a jdbc url string (from a spring, tomcat, war) like this: 
`jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?ApplicationName=myapp1`.

Then, in pg_activity I can see the application name that started the connection.

However, the company I work for, uses EDB database (flavor of postgres as I understand it). When I deployed my spring application there, the application name did not show up in pg_activity. 
So, I reasoned that this is not an accepted connection string argument / parameter. So I googled for it and didn't really find an (alternative) argument to accomplish this. See also https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/9.4/jdbc/Postgres_Plus_Advanced_Server_JDBC_Connector_Guide.1.13.html

Do you know a way to get this working?

Comment: BTW: Other applications do manage to get their name into pg_activity tabel. So, it is not that EDB doesn't support it at all.

Comment: see bottom of this page for default settings https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/connect.html#connection-parameters